# Getting Rspec to Recognize Macros for Capybara's Specials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, config

When adding macros to Rspec's config, you have to specify the type of test it'll be accessed by. For instance, you might type:

```
config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

How do you get this to work with Capybara, whose type (:feature) is seemingly not recognized by [Rspec's config](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/commit/fc5cdbb603f0e66f9f3d19a0a60a775e124fb218). Trying something like this does not work:

```
config.extend FeatureMacros, :type => :feature
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you type `extend`, all my settings are `include` and they works.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ... others

  # Session helpers - For Capybara
  config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature

  # Controller helpers
  config.include ControllerMacros, type: :controller

end
```

And the module files are in `spec/support`. If sub module, they are in sub folder like `spec/support/features/

Example of Capybara helpers

```
# spec/support/features/session_helpers.rb
require 'spec_helper'

module Features
  module SessionHelpers

    def user_sign_in
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works. If you use include, you don't have to set the `type` either.